# Do items which add to some ability affect your skill modifier?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, equipment, ability-scores

I just received armor which adds +2 to my charisma. Does it also affect my skills like performance and persuasion?

If possible, could you link some source in your answer? I searched and didn't find any conclusive answer.

Comment: What item is this? Is it an official item or one your GM made?

Comment: I have closed your question as a duplicate as I feel it has effectively been asked before and that [the linked question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/156277) answers it. This isn't a bad thing, and it actually *helps* people find that linked question more easily, but if you feel that your question *isn't* answered there, feel free to explain why with an [edit] or a comment. But also welcome to RPG.SE! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already done so and feel free to visit the [help] or leave a comment here if you have any questions. Best of luck and happy gaming!

Comment: Which version of "the rules" do you use as a source? Players Handbook? Basic Rules? Something from D&DBeyond? Some random web site? Some d&d wiki site?

Comment: Could you quote the specific description of the item? Does it add 2 to your Charisma score, or something else?